# jQuery draggable/contenteditable code not responding correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable, contenteditable

I looked up this code from another post:

```
<div id="d" contenteditable="true">
    Text to edit
</div>

<script>
$("#d")
    .draggable()
    .click(function(){
        $(this).draggable( "option", "disabled", true );
    })
    .blur(function(){
        $(this).draggable( 'option', 'disabled', false);
    });
</script>
```

The link is this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/UH9UE/222/

The problem is, when the jQuery version is on 1.7, the highlighting and 'selectability' of the object is smooth. But when it is switched to 2.0.2, it doesn't function the same. I am using the later version for my project that's why I can't roll back to the older version.

Comment: In your demo, jQuery 2.x works fine to me. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: When I select the object to edit the text, the background changes -- greyish, just like it's disabled. One more thing, I can't easily select the object and deselect it (i.e. sometimes it stay grey).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to achieve this with css.
Add this function in your javascript

```
$.fn.drags = function(opt) {
    opt = $.extend({handle:"",cursor:""}, opt);

    if(opt.handle === "") {
        var $el = this;
    } else {
        var $el = this.find(opt.handle);
    }
    return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function(e) {
        if(opt.handle === "") {
            var $drag = $(this).addClass('draggable');
        } else {
            var $drag = $(this).addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
        }
        var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
            drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
            drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
            pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
            pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;
        $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents().on("mousemove", function(e) {
            $('.draggable').offset({
                top:e.pageY + pos_y - drg_h,
                left:e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w
            }).on("mouseup", function() {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
            });
        });
        //e.preventDefault(); // uncomment to avoid making editable
    }).on("mouseup", function() {
        if(opt.handle === "") {
            $(this).removeClass('draggable');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active-handle').parent().removeClass('draggable');
        }
    });

}
```

And simply call it using this

```
$("#d").drags();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UH9UE/365/)

Made some modifications from the original code found [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/) to suit your needs.